# Slick Slider - create a link from another page

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Is it possible to create a link to a slide in slick slider? Example: my goal is to create QR codes with the URL of a page and load the slider and the current slide is number 5.

Comment: Try to add each slide an unique Id and than the click action points to the element with that Id. I'm not sure if it works, but it's the same principle to scroll a page to a component

Comment: Didn't work with unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it a few ways but given that you want to create URL's you could pass in the slide number as a query string for example you have a website called `www.example.com` you have a hyperlink set to your page like so `www.example.com/subpage/?slideNum=2`

On the page where you have your slick-slider you would add an event to first listen for the slick slider being created, then check to see if there is a URL parameter set to do a `slickGoTo` event like so:-

```
$(".slick").on("init", function (e, slickInstance) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const myParam = params.get("slideNum");
  if (Number(myParam)) {
    slickInstance.slickGoTo(myParam);
  }
});

$(".slick").slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1
});
```

This method allows you to still go to the URL with or without a query parameter and also offers flexibility for you to change the slide number relatively easily.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Now I have another issue (scroll to the section), but i't's another question :)

Comment: The full URL (website in Wordpress) to scroll to section would be example.com/pagename?slideNum=2#sectionID